# utf-8 in htmlspecialchars() function

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, htmlspecialchars

I have a slight confusion regarding using UTF-8 in the htmlspecialchars() function like this:

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

What I do not understand is, does using this make htmlspecialchars() create a UTF-8 code or that it just informs htmlspecialchars() the $string is UTF-8 so that it does not mess up.
I mean are we specifying? the input or are we specifying the output?

Hope it makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter is just to tell htmlspecialchars() not to mess up Unicode strings. You need to tell htmlspecialchars() what the input encoding is. Consequentially, that is also the encoding used in the output.

Remember that PHP does not support Unicode, so it does not care about what charset you are using. That parameter in htmlspecialchars() is only used to tell PHP not to mess up with your bytes.

Answer (score 3):

The third parameter is for both input *and* output. If you want to convert between character sets, you'll have to do it externally e.g. using the iconv function.

Comment: I don't understand, can you give more detail? How does it specify both? Are you saying that if the input is in UTF-8 then the output out of htmlspecialchars() can only be UTF-8?

Comment: If the input is UTF-8, and you specify UTF-8 as the third param, then the output will be UTF8. If your goal is to get the output from UTF-8 into, say, Latin1, then you'll need to use iconv after the htmlspecialchars call to do the conversion.

HTML escaping and character encoding are two different things; htmlspecialchars does one but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

I think the manual is straight forward about this

> Defines encoding used in conversion. If omitted, the default value for this argument is ISO-8859-1 in versions of PHP prior to 5.4.0, and UTF-8 from PHP 5.4.0 onwards.

This is about input and output.